# How can i create a yum repositoy that points to online servers?

Tags: yum, centos-7

I am getting error like

`http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/9b838fdcbdb8321433aa7d87eb6b0b4603fdb9e754ee2adeb6b0d3329ac03ec0-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
http://centos-hcm.viettelidc.com.vn/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/9b838fdcbdb8321433aa7d87eb6b0b4603fdb9e754ee2adeb6b0d3329ac03ec0-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
http://mirror.fibergrid.in/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/9b838fdcbdb8321433aa7d87eb6b0b4603fdb9e754ee2adeb6b0d3329ac03ec0-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
 and more`

the reason is `9b838fdcbdb8321433aa7d87eb6b0b4603fdb9e754ee2adeb6b0d3329ac03ec0-filelists.sqlite.bz2` is not there online instead 
the xml file `http://centos.excellmedia.net/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml` contains 
`<location href="<location href="repodata/308b19b243c882f0278206ea4ffc4e120df78c0218867917916fd437e4d0ea49-filelists.sqlite.bz2"/>`

how do i make yum point to correct file online.

I want to try this but i am not sure if it creates more problems
`createrepo -g http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/repodata/repomd.xml http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch`

http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os contains the following links and all of them are giving me similar error because a different filename exists there

```
http://centosmirror.go4hosting.in/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://mirror.nbrc.ac.in/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://centos.mirror.net.in/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://centos.excellmedia.net/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://centos.webwerks.com/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://mirror.fibergrid.in/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://mirror.dhakacom.com/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://mirrors.digipower.vn/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://mirrors.vonline.vn/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
```

Comment: Not sure. I used a different approach. Downloaded the repo, then synced it daily so that the rest of servers did not have to go online instead they used the downloaded internal copy. I assume that every repo has a different file (I was some time ago that I have set it up like described)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was simple,

I just downloaded the `repormod.xml` into the repective repo directory mentioned in the `yum.conf` file and ran `yum clean all` and `yum makecache`

```
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
```

it worked.